# Usage of sentence after “as”

Tags: conjunctions

Can i use a sentence after “as” or “in the way” as is the case with sentences below.

1) This sentence can be translated as “they will never come again” .

2) This sentence can be translated in the way that “they will never come”.

Comment: So I don't know the name of the grammar rule or whatever it is for this, but as a native English speaker #1 sounds normal and #2 sounds kind of weird or awkward. I don't know why though- I hope that helps a little!

Answer (score 2):

The most natural use is

> This sentence can be translated **as** “they will never come again”

Your alternative

> This sentence can be translated **in the way** that “they will never come”.

would be better as

> **A way that** this sentence can be translated **is** “they will never come”.